# SQL constraint between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have two tables, let's call them A and B

In table B, I have a foreign key to A.

```
B {
    ...
    a_id
    value
    ...
}
```

I would like to add a constraint such that multiple entries in B having the same 'a_id' and 'value' are not allowed.

How can I do that? I suppose it's something trivial and I'm sorry if it ends to be so.

Comment: You're looking for a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a unique constraint or index on `B`:

```
create unique index unq_b_aid_value on b(a_id, value);
```

You also want the foreign key constraint to from `b(a_id)` to `a(a_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You would use in your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CONSTRAINT 
    constraint_name 
UNIQUE 
     (a_id, value)
```

Alternately, to add it to your existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT 
     constraint_name 
UNIQUE 
    (a_id, value)
```